# How to replace ?query with /query

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to make it so when someone does example.com/page.php/query it works as a $_GET (example.com/page.php?q=query) for the query

How would I do this?

Would this be done with the page.php's code or would I do it in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to route a request like /test/something to internally rewrite so that the content at /test.php?whatever=something gets served, you would use these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*?)/?$ /test.php?whatever=$1 [L]
```